# Why this loop corrupts the array?

Tags: c++

I am posting here because I need your help with this issue. I have been trying to fix it by my own but I had not luck. I really do not understand what is happening. If you look at my code you will notice that I have the following loop :

```
 for (j = 0; j < total_scores; j++)
        {

        cout << "P is " << p << endl ;
        cout << "Enter score : ";
        cin >> scores[p];
        p++;

        }
```

Well , If I enable this piece of the code ,  the array that stores the names is corrupt and I obtain a weird result for the position 0  :    4@  and one error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'scores' was corrupted."

I really do not understand why , or how to fix this.Without the loop that ask for scores the loop with the names remains intact. I do not understand what is happening here if they are two separated elements.

Any idea? I really appreciate your time and your attention .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int total_students=   2 ;
    const int scores_students = 1 ;
    const int total_scores = scores_students*total_students;

    string names[total_students];
    double scores[total_scores];
    double average[scores_students];
    double averages=0.0;



    int i;
    int j  =  0 ;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int p = 0 ;



    for (i = 0; i < total_students; i++)
    {
        cout << "I is " << i << endl;
        cout << "Enter name : "; 
        cin >> names[i];

        for (j = 0; j < total_scores; j++)
        {

        cout << "P is " << p << endl ;
        cout << "Enter score : ";
        cin >> scores[p];
        p++;

        }

    }


    for (m = 0 ; m < total_students ; m++)
    {

        cout << "\nName : " << names[m] << endl << endl ;
        //cout << "Average :  " << average[m] << endl;

    }

    system("pause");
    system("pause");
}
```

What I need is the program to ask for name , and then the test results based on "scores_students" , then the second name and the next scores. And so on

Example of Input that I am looking for :

```
Name Score1
Peter 20
Mark  100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a loop inside a loop, so `p` can end up being incremented to 4, so you try to access `scores[4]` when the array size is only 2.

Based on comments, looks like the answer is that the "j loop" should be `for (j = 0; j < scores_student; j++)` instead of `total_scores` which causes the overflow mentioned above.

Comment: Or possibly he should only be looping `j` up to `scores_students`

Comment: Problem is that I need user to enter "Name A" and their 2 scores , then Name B and their 2 scores...and so . With your response what It will do is : Ask for names and then the scores . Example of input that I am looking for :  Peter 20 30 Mark 10 10

Comment: What do you mean "'Name A' and their 2 scores"? What 2 scores? Should `scores_student` be 2 if you want 2 scores per person?

Comment: @John3136 You are right. Number of scores should be based on the variable "scores_students" . I put 2 as an example . Basically what I need is the program to ask for name , and then the test results based on "scores_students" , then the second name and the next scores. And so on

Comment: I think @TheDark is right - j just has to loop to scores_students.